# React native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, bundle

I am having issues with expo compiling my JavaScript bundle after it runs my code getting to 98% then it stops and display cannot connect to development server on my console and afterwards this even makes my vs code editor start misbehaving and getting slower in efficiency, please I don’t know what’s wrong

I have been running it several times and it has been displaying the result of my code on my device emulator, it just started suddenly, I am expecting to have a result of my project on my emulator

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.